# SSL configuration with play framework and the chain file

Tags: ssl, ssh, playframework

I have configured play internal web-server with SSL with following configuration:

```
https.port=9443
certificate.key.file=conf/host.key
certificate.file=conf/host.cert
```

but the problem is that the newest firefox is unable to authenticate and gives the following message:

**The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.**

in Apache2 you can specify the chain file with SSLCertificateChainFile, anyone knows how to do it in play?

thanks!

Comment: Is this a self signed certificate or was it signed by a CA?

Comment: signed by a CA (godaddy), but when you download the godaddy certificates, it contained 2 files, one certificate and another one is gd_bundel.cer which is the chain file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest Update: Even after combining chain file with main cirtificate, firefox is complaining about untrusted connection. I am giving up. I will use Appache httpd in the front.

Finally, I was able to setup ssl with godaddy cirtificates, directly in play framework webserver.

In application.conf add the lines.

```
%prod.http.port=80
%prod.https.port=443
%prod.certificate.key.file=conf/hostname.key
%prod.certificate.file=conf/hostname.combined.crt
```

Combine the CA signed certificate and the bundle file into one.

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in hostname.crt -text > hostname.combined.crt
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in "sf_bundle.crt" -text >> hostname.combined.crt
```

And copy the following files to your conf folder (Don't put it in a sub-folder. It will not work)

```
sf_bundle.crt
hostname.crt
hostname.csr
hostname.key
```

Answer (score 0):

In another forum, I came across a solution with which you can combine your certificate and chain file into one file. This way you don’t have to specify a separate chain file. Hope this helps.
http://help.globalscape.com/help/eft5/admin/certificate_chaining.htm